# Ultraviolet Radiation simulation in blender

Tags: cloth-simulation

i HAVE NOT TRY ANYTHING YET. can i simulate Ultraviolet Radiation light in blender? Its urgent please

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

No.

Blender is not a physical simulator. It provides some simulations, none of which are for light, and are only to create visually appealing/plausible effects, rather than for scientific accuracy.

Rendering engines such as cycles could be viewed as a simulation, however this is not a physically accurate simulation, in particular, it does not handle wavelength at all (it uses an RGB colour space which is a subset of visible light, so ultraviolet is definitely excluded).

Being designed for visual effects, blender doesn't really cater for things that aren't visible.